# Using shared access signatures in Xamarin with Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an app developed using Xamarin Forms.  The app connects to a container on Azure to read a couple of text files.  The text files don't contain any confidential or secret information, just some publicly available information that the app uses.

I am able to connect to the storage container and read the blob without issue however I am readying the app for release to the App store and Google Play store so was following this guide around using Shared Access Keys to connect to Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

To be honest, I am a bit confused as to which approach I should use.  The app itself will be connecting to the container and reading the blob, so it won't be an actual "user" as such like joeB, or JaneB.  That makes me think a user delegated SAS is not the way to go, although the documentation seems to suggest this is the most secure option.

I also noticed the user delegated sas token itself expires after a period of time and the app started crashing when trying to autheticate/connect.  I am not sure if that is also the case with a service SAS and account SAS.

Basically, for my use case (an app reading a text file in a container in Azure), which is the best option for me to use based on those listed in the link above?  Has anyone else done something similar?  If so, how did you secure your connection string?

Thanks!

Comment: If the blob is publicly available, then you do not need SAS. You can simply read the blob's content using its URL.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea.  The blob is not currently publicly available but I guess there is not real reason it couldn't be, there's nothing confidential in it.